# Deep Learning with Python book quotes that The final output is a 2D tensor of shape (timesteps, output_features) but final_output_sequence is 1D

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

In the **`Listing 6.21 Numpy implementation of a simple RNN`** (chapter 6) of the book, "Deep Learning with Python", written by Francois Chollet, it has been mentioned that the

"Variable, **`final_output_sequence`** is **`the final output is a 2D tensor of shape (timesteps, output_features).`**"

But I have replicated the code and observed that, it is a **`1D`** Tensor of shape **`(timesteps*output_features,)`**.

Code to replicate the issue is shown below:

```
import numpy as np

timesteps = 100
input_features = 32
output_features = 64

inputs = np.random.random((timesteps, input_features))
state_t = np.zeros((output_features,))
W = np.random.random((output_features, input_features))
U = np.random.random((output_features, output_features))
b = np.random.random((output_features,))

successive_outputs = []
for input_t in inputs:
    output_t = np.tanh(np.dot(W, input_t) + np.dot(U, state_t) + b)
    successive_outputs.append(output_t)
    state_t = output_t
final_output_sequence = np.concatenate(successive_outputs, axis=0)
```

Can someone help me get the 2D Tensor with shape (timesteps, output_features) from the above code. It would be great if someone can explain what is the reason for this discrepancy.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try `final_output_sequence = np.concatenate([successive_outputs], axis=0)`. Please refer to [numpy.concatenate()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html).

Comment: Thank you very much gider_yugang, it worked. You can add it as an answer so that I can Accept it and Up vote it.